# Exact value involving ProductLog

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

By manual manipulation, it's not too difficult to show that the value of the following expression is exactly $1.$ How to convince Mathematica to do the simplification?

```
2/3 - ProductLog[-(Log[2]/(3 2^(1/3)))]/Log[2]
```

Comment: The crux of the problem is that `-(Log[2]/(3 2^(1/3)))` is not easily recognized to be the same as `-(Log[2]/3) Exp[-(Log[2]/3)]`.

Comment: @J.M. the expression is not created by me, but (more or less) the output of `Solve[2^(n - 1) == 3 n - 2]`

Comment: @J.M. even with your substitution, the simplification fails to give $1$

Comment: I was explaining why it was failing. `ProductLog[-1/8 Exp[-1/8]]` evaluates as expected, but *Mathematica* is not sufficiently smart to figure out that a similar operation applies for `ProductLog[-(Log[2]/(3 2^(1/3)))]`. Consider sending Support a message.

Comment: Mathematica 13.0 or 12.3 `2/3 - ProductLog[-(Log[2]/(3 2^(1/3)))]/Log[2] // FullSimplify` simplifies to 1 without any problem